# how to make curl accept secure cookies overt http connection

Tags: http, curl, cookies, insecure-connection

I am using curl to connect to an http server which sends back a secure flagged cookie, and I found out that curl doesn't handle such cookies (secure cookies received over http connection), in other words : even using `-c cookieFile` switch, such cookies are not saved.

A workaround is to use `-D` switch to save all headers then manually (externally to curl) read the cookie from the file and set it in the curl command to send it back to server.

I want to know if there is a possibility (may be I am missing some curl options) to make curl support such cookies ? I tried to look into curl manual but nothing useful to my use case.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** With recent versions of cURL it is **no longer possible** to save cookies with the `secure` attribute in conjunction with cookie related switches.

According the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html) cURL removed the ability to save cookies with the `secure` attribute in order to satisfy the RFC draft [draft-ietf-httpbis-cookie-alone-01](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cookie-alone-01). This RFC draft mandates that `secure` cookies are only supposed to be handled, saved or overwritten by an HTTP client if said cookie was transferred over HTTPS.

I just stumbled over the exactly the same problem, so I can offer two alternatives:

1. use a cURL version before the feature was implemented

   - cURL < v7.46.0
   - see respective [Github issue](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/5473) which led to this behaviour
2. dump the headers manually with `curl -i` or `curl -D` and extract the cookies

   - example to save all `secure` cookies and save them in a file `cookies.txt`

   ```
    curl -i http://server.com | grep "Set-Cookie: " | sed 's/Set-Cookie: //g' > cookies.txt
   ```

Now, a cookie jar would be useless if you would not use the cookies inside. Especially regarding the second alternative, it may be necessary to remove the `Secure` attribute in order to make cURL send the saved cookies back to the web server.